# Portlets not below content in Sunburst theme?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

The [Sunbirst Github page](https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.sunburst) states:

> When viewed on a device with less than 640px width, the portlets
>   neatly tuck under the main content area. This means that the site
>   works well with CSS-enabled devices like tablets and phones that may
>   have limited resolution.

How can I disable this feature? That is, I want the portlets to be always displaced at the left or right side, regardless of the display size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mobile.css` stylesheet defines what the layout is on a mobile device. You can clear that file in your own skin layer.

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed-width via CSS, #visual-portal-wrapper suites well for this:

```
#visual-portal-wrapper {
    width: 999px;          /* or any other absolute value */
    margin: 0 auto;        /* horizontal centering */
}
```